# Finding DataGridColumn from Header Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can I find the DataGridTextColumn from the HeaderTemplate template? Is there a way to perform this using only XAML? I have tried FindAncestor of type DataGridTextColumn but it is not found.

I know DataGridTextColumn is not part of the visual tree. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're trying to do with the column, and where you're trying to access it from in the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the whole column object? The DataContext will be whatever you pass in as header, e.g.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

This will cause a red header with the text "Name".

If you actually need the column you could use an `ElementName` binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Run Text=" - " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=nameColumn, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This shows "Name" and the column width in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the column by index in the datagrid using find ancestor works.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Run Text=" - " />
                    <Run Text="{Binding Columns[0].ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```